# Guidelines for travel to Canada from international destination and then connecting domestic flight - CDN citizen

Tags: canada, canadian-citizens, covid-19

I have been searching for an answer to this but have not been able to get a definite answer. I am a Canadian citizen and will be flying from a foreign destination to Toronto and then have a domestic flight from Toronto to Vancouver. How would mandatory self-isolation of 14 days work in this case (self-isolate at Toronto or at Vancouver)? What other guidelines should I be aware of and what type of questions should I ask my airline? Any suggestion would be helpful because at this point I can't find any answer specific to this situation (foreign-YYZ-YVR).

Thank you

Comment: This https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/services/diseases/2019-novel-coronavirus-infection/latest-travel-health-advice.html#domestic seems to state that you must self-isolate on arrival at your final destination

Comment: Thanks Traveller. I read that page multiple times but somehow always missed that part (may be because I was on a mobile device). Thanks again for pointing it out. You can add that as answer if you want and I will mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are symptom-free, you are required to self-isolate on arrival at your final destination.

Source: https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/services/diseases/2019-novel-coronavirus-infection/latest-travel-health-advice.html#domestic

As of March 30, 2020, all passengers flying in Canada will be subject to a health check prior to boarding. You will not be permitted to board if you:

- show any symptoms of COVID-19 or
- have been refused boarding in the past 14 days due to a medical reason related to COVID-19 or
- are subject to a provincial or local public health order

This also applies to travellers arriving from outside Canada.

If you are arriving from outside Canada and are deemed safe to fly, you may board a connecting flight to your destination. However, upon arrival at your final destination, you must go directly to the place where you will isolate, and remain there for 14 days. This is because you are still at risk of developing symptoms and infecting others.

You may be subject to additional provincial or territorial public health measures at your final destination.

If you have symptoms of COVID-19, you will not be allowed to board any flight until:

- 14 days have passed, or
- you present a medical certificate confirming that your symptoms are not related to COVID-19

If you have signs or symptoms consistent with COVID-19, you will not be allowed to use public transportation to travel to the place where you will isolate.